# How to adapt an image inside mat-grid-list angular 4

Tags: angular, angular-material

In my angular 4 project I want to show some thumbnail in a [mat-grid-list](https://material.angular.io/components/grid-list/overview).
All the thumbnails have width or height 300.

If you look in the image you can see that if the images have width = 300 like the Chrysanthemum jpg it works good,
but if the images have height = 300, like first one, it doesn't works.
It seems that mat-grid try to adapt the image with their width.

Is there a way to fit all the picture inside the mat-grid-tile?
[image]

Comment: Hello, were you able to fid a good solution for this one?

Comment: Hi, I used bootstrap row and column to create my own grid, and I use css to fit the image